# How to disable dead keys

Tags: x11, keyboard, dead-keys

I have a Debian 11 box running the Cinnamon DE.  My keyboard layout is, per `localectl status`:

```
   System Locale: LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: uk
      X11 Layout: gb
       X11 Model: pc105
```

while `$GTK_IM_MODULE` is `ibus`.

My problem is that this setup has *dead keys* enabled and I really don't want that.

My question: what must I change to turn dead keys off?

Strange observation: I have a second debian-11 machine which runs emacs EXWM as window manager and the exact same keyboard setup (as far as I can see) and here I have no dead keys exactly as I want.  Does the desktop environment impact this issue?

Comment: This could be Ibus or, in GTK programs, GTK modules, so have you tried with Xim? See for example [Disable transient symbols for compose and dead keys in GTK programs (disclaimer: my answer in a a site in which I'm moderator)](https://linux.codidact.com/posts/285653).

Comment: @Quasimodo Thanks but I get the same behaviour with Xim.

Answer (score 0):

`localectl` reports the selected *system-wide default* keyboard settings, while your DE probably maintains *per-user keyboard settings* that can augment or completely override the system defaults for the duration of that user's login session.

The normal way to get rid of dead keys would be to pick the `nodeadkeys` *variant* of your chosen keyboard layout instead of the default variant. Unfortunately, the `gb` layout does not seem to have such a variant defined for it (check with `localectl list-x11-keymap-variants gb`).

If you make the change with `localectl`, the DE's memory of your current user-specific settings may actually work against you, because the DE will still remember that you previously used the dead-keys variant and will switch  back to it when you log in. You should make the change in the settings tool of your DE, instead: that should both make the change effective immediately and let the DE remember the new setting.

Comment: Thanks.  I agree that the problem is, at least partly the lack of a `nodeadkeys` variant of the `gb` layout.  But I am still puzzled by the fact that I have no deadkeys under EXWM. How can I instruct Cinnamon to behave the same way?